# perl only print if value met otherwise don't print

Tags: perl

How do i get perl not to print if the are no matches found.
this is what i have at present.

```
    if ( "$types" eq "aa") {
    $types="bbbb";
    }
    else {
    if ("$types" eq "S") {
    $types="xx";
    @TICKET="yy";
    }}

    $value= &read_location;
    if ("$value" ne "0"){
    print "@record  NOT KNOWN PLEASE DETAILS  \n";

    }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: When this code runs it will always print "@records not known" even if there are none, I want it to not print anything if there are no records, a print else don't print sort of thing

Comment: Then you need to look at the value being returned from the &read_location function and see why it is always a value other than "0"

Comment: Sometimes it is a value of 0 sometimes it is not, so when it is not can it be set not t o print the details, ie will an else statement work?

Answer (score 0):

This code will only print "@record NOT KNOWN" if the value returned from `read_location` is NOT equal to "0". If the value returned IS equal to "0" then nothing will print.

```
$value = &read_location;

if ($value ne "0"){
    print "@record  NOT KNOWN PLEASE DETAILS  \n";
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want the message to print when the value IS equal to "0"

```
$value = &read_location;

if ($value eq "0"){
    print "@record  NOT KNOWN PLEASE DETAILS  \n";
}
```

You can read more about Perl if-else constructs  [at this page](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/ifelsifelse.html)

Comment: It will still print one line though ie if value is 0 it will print  'blabla not know etc' but if value is not 0 it will still print '@record not known etc'